# Error 404 Unable to process request in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have 2 folders:

**/var/www/img/2014/ (for images)**

and

**/var/www/img/2014/th (for thumbnails)**

If I loading image from **/var/www/img/2014/** for example: 
http://url.com/img/2014/1400057171thinkpad10-lenovo,X-Y-435382-3.png
All normal loads.

But if I loading an image from **/var/www/img/2014/th**, displays the error:

> Error 404 Unable to process request
>   "img/2014/th/1400057171thinkpad10-lenovo, X-Y-435382-3.png".

Code /var/www/protected/config/main.php

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
    //not show index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
),
```

Folder permissions 775. 
I think that this is related to the routing, not allowing me to the "th", how can I fix this error in Yii v1.? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's routing related. Does the thumbnail exists? Is the path correct? Check the case of the path and filename. The error is produced by the router but the router will only be involved if there was no physical file found. Which I think is here the case.

Comment: `http://url.com/img/2014/1400057171thinkpad10-lenovo,X-Y-435382-3.png` there is a `,` between `lenovo` and `X` - maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Jurik, How could I not see this error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

u did not give proper name for image

when ever u upload image that time u have to replace image name as timestamp.

main issue is image name is not proper.